# mongoose changing update on pre('update') does not work on validation

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

My Code below contains the schema and a pre('update') middleware to manipulate the name property of the schema. Actually I just want to add a suffix to the name property if the value already exists in the Item Collection.

```
const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  name : {type : String, required : true, unique : true, trim : true},
  ...
})

ItemSchema.pre("update", async function() {
  let name = this.getUpdate().$set.name;
  if (!name) return Promise.resolve();
  let count = await ItemModel.find({name}).count().exec();
  if(count>0) name = name + "_SOME_SUFFIX_BY_SOME_LOGIC";
  this.getUpdate().$set.name = name;
});

ItemSchema.plugin(require('mongoose-unique-validator'));

const ItemModel = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
module.exports = ItemModel;
```

when I then try to update/patch the name property, the count seems to correctly get the number 1 and updates the name by the suffix. Afterwards, I correctly update the name in the update object with the correctly manipulated name (whereby the name with the suffix does surely not exist in the collection)

but now, when I try to update, I get the following Error:

> Validation failed: name: Error, expected `name` to be unique. Value:
>   `[name]_SOME_SUFFIX_BY_SOME_LOGIC'

So it tells me, that the new suffixed name already exist in the database, even though it does not.

(I have looked for the suffixed name inside the database, but I can assure It is not there, Since I'm running this on test collections, there are not many entries yet)

node version : 8.1.1 mongoose version : 5.1.3 system : ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I actualy found out, that mongoose-unique-validator is the problem here. I found A comment in a mongoose issue describing why.

> Because mongoose-unique-validator relies on async operations like
>   .count() to verify whether a document exists in the database, it's
>   possible for two .count() calls to execute roughly at the same time,
>   both get 0 back, and then both insert into MongoDB. You'd need to do
>   some locking operation to make it work properly in the general case.
>
> The only way to work around this is to use only one process and set
>   your mongodb connection pool size to 1, but that limits the amount of
>   app servers you can run and will only work so long as mongodb retains
>   its legacy behavior of blocking operations on a per-connection basis.

[issue link](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3589)